# Pythonic way to do strategy design pattern,avoid use switch base on string compare

Tags: python, design-patterns, datetime

Here are two functions, which are quite similar. The type of `dtIndex` is `pandas` `DatetimeIndex` and the only difference is the `i.dayofyear` part. There are days of week, month of year, week of month, week of year I still need to implement.

```
def extract_day_of_year(dtIndex):
    dayofyear_arr = []
    for i in dtIndex:
        dayofyear_arr.append(i.dayofyear)
    return dayofyear_arr

def extract_day_of_month(dtIndex):
    dayofmonth_arr = []
    for i in dtIndex:
        dayofmonth_arr.append(i.dayofmonth)
    return dayofmonth_arr
```

Is there a "Pythonic" way than `switch` according to an additional `str` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The most flexible approach would use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

```
def extract(attr, datetimeindex):
    return [getattr(x, attr) for x in datetimeindex]

# Now, for example:
extract_day_of_year = partial(extract, attr='dayofyear')

# or
def extract_day_of_month(datetimeindex):
    return extract('dayofmonth', datetimeindex)
```

Alternatively with [`attrgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.attrgetter):

```
def extract(attr, datetimeindex):
    return map(attrgetter(attr), datetimeindex)
```

I've also converted the `for` loop into a list comprehension (first) or `map()` (second), both of which spare you from needing to name a temporary variable.

Comment: need to `from functools import partial` first,and final `extract_day_of_year(datetimeindex=mydatetimeindex)`.Didn't know there is `partial` and `getattr` before.Thanks a lot!